# Conditional expectations and the tower property

Tags: statistics, measure-theory

What can I say about $E(XE(X|\mathcal{G}))$ if $X$ is $\mathcal{F}$-measurable and $\mathcal{G}$ is a sub-$\sigma$-algebra of $\mathcal{F}$. I konw that the tower property somehow kicks in but I always fail to get it. Any help?

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to assume $X\in L^2$ (at the very least you need $\mathbb{E}[X\mid\mathcal{G}]\in L^2$).  Then iterated expectation gives
$$
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}[X\mathbb{E}[X\mid\mathcal{G}]]
&=\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[X\mathbb{E}[X\mid\mathcal{G}]\mid\mathcal{G}]]\\
&=\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[X\mid\mathcal{G}]\cdot\mathbb{E}[X\mid\mathcal{G}]]\\
&=\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[X\mid\mathcal{G}]^2]
\end{align*}
$$
Unfortunately that is pretty much all you could say.  If $X$ is real-valued, then this expectation between $(\mathbb{E}X)^2$ and $\mathbb{E}X^2$, the former achieved by having the $\mathcal{G}$ independent of $X$ (such as the trivial $\sigma$-algebra) and the latter by $\mathcal{G}=\sigma(X)$ or larger.

Comment: Thanks, this helps a lot. Can you clarify the last sentence? I know indeed that $X$ Is real valued (it is defined as a random variable). Does this mean I can drop the outer expectation and thus have everything collapse to $(\mathbb{E}(X))^2$? I didn't get the part that this gets to the second term.

Comment: No you can't drop the expectation.  Recall $\mathbb{E}[-\mid\mathcal{G}]\colon L^2\to L^2$ is the orthogonal projection onto the closed subspace $L^2(\mathcal{G})$.  If $\mathcal{G}$ contains $\sigma(X)$ then it projects $X$ to $X$.  If $\mathcal{G}$ is independent of $X$, then the projection minimizes least square error so must be $\mathbb{E}X$ a.s.  Also recall by convention $\mathbb{E}X^2$ (and similar) is defined as $\mathbb{E}[X^2]$.

Comment: Ok, thanks! so how do I know if $\mathcal{G}$ is independent of $X$. It's not explicitly given in the problem but can I imply it from what is given - $X$ is a random variable $X \in L^2(\Omega, \mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$ and $ \mathbb{E}(X| \mathcal{G}) \in L^2(\Omega, \mathcal{G},\mathbb{P})$, and $\mathcal{G}$ is sub-sigma-algebra of $\mathcal{F}$